# Error in Select query using SQL Server in VB.NET Winforms

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, select

This query is not returning any value and not causing any error:

```vb
Dim cmdAs1 As String
Dim daAs1 As SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter
Dim dsAs1 As DataSet
Dim dtAs1 As DataTable

cmdAs1 = "SELECT * FROM [SN_Male_Quest_2018].[dbo].[Section_3] WHERE sub_village_id= '" & sub_village_id & "' and household_id= '" & household_id & "' and hrid= '" & male & "' and hrid= '" & female & "' and hrid= '" & adolscent & "' and hrid= '" & respid & "'"
daAs1 = New SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter(cmdAs1, cnn)
dtAs1 = New DataTable()
dsAs1 = New DataSet()
daAs1.Fill(dsAs1, "Section_3")
dtAs1 = dsAs1.Tables("Section_3")
lbloperator.Text = dtAs1.Rows.Count

If (dtAs1.Rows.Count.Equals(0)) Then
```

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection - check out [Little Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/)

Comment: If the result set is empty then there are no records in the database that match the filter. That's all there is to it. As you haven't bothered to even show us what the filter is, what do you expect us to say? I'd wager that you haven't even looked at the SQL code yourself. The VB code that builds the SQL code is not the SQL code. Apart from that, don;t use string concatenation to insert values into SQL code. Always use parameters. You'll avoid all manner of issues that way, one of which may be causing the problem here.

Comment: By the way, if what you want is a `DataTable` then just create a `DataTable`. The `DataSet` is pointless. That `Fill` method will accept a `DataTable` as an argument. Also, the `Fill` method returns the number of records retrieved, so there's no need to separately test the row count of the `DataTable`. Finally, while using `.Equals(0)` is not wrong but no one does it because it's silly when you can use the more clear `= 0`.

Comment: you should check your `WHERE` condition: `and hrid= '" & male & "' and hrid= '" & female & "' and hrid= '" & adolscent & "' and hrid= '" & respid & "'"`. unlikely it will ever match

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep your connection object local to the method where it is used. This allows you to control that it is closed and disposed. `Using...End Using` blocks to this for you even if there is an error. In this example both the connection and the command are included in the Using.

As was mentioned in comments by @devio you cannot have a single field equal several different values. I can only assume you meant "OR".

Always use parameters. I had to guess at the datatype and field size. Please check your database and adjust the code accordingly.

```
Private Sub FillDataTable(sub_village_id As String, household_id As String, male As String, female As String, adolscent As String, respid As String)
    Dim dtAs1 As New DataTable
    Using cn As New SqlConnection("Your connection string"),
            cmd As New SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM [Section_3] WHERE sub_village_id= @villageID and household_id= @householdID and (hrid= @hrIDMale Or hrid= @hrIDFemale Or hrid= @hrIDAdolescent Or hrid= @hrIDResID);", cn)
        With cmd.Parameters
            .Add("@villageID", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100).Value = sub_village_id
            .Add("@householdID", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100).Value = household_id
            .Add("@hrIDMale", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100).Value = male
            .Add("@hrIDFemale", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100).Value = female
            .Add("@hrIDAdolescent", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100).Value = adolscent
            .Add("@hrIDResID", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100).Value = respid
        End With
        cn.Open()
        dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader)
    End Using
    lbloperator.Text = dt.Rows.Count.ToString
    If dt.Rows.Count = 0 Then
        'Your code here
    End If
End Sub
```